# Excel: how ensure cells contain numbers 1-6 or comma separated numbers 1-6?

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I have question and answer spreadsheets with up to a couple hundred rows in them.  One column in each row indicates a correct answer by entering a number from 1 to 6 or multiple answers separated by commas like 1,3,5. I'd like to enforce this rule on every row and not allow input of anything else.

I find can't a way to use Custom Data Validation and am not sure how to use a function in each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select your range of interest, for example `A1:A10`
- Add the following formula as a custom data validation:

  ```
  =IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[preceding::*=.  or .*0!=0 or .*1>6 or .*1<1]"),"")=""
  ```

You'd need Excel2013 onwards but the formula will validate the string value to have:

- No duplicate values.
- No values other than numbers.
- No values above 6.
- No values below 1.
- Only comma will work as a valid seperator.

The `A1` in the formula is relative so validation for `A10` will work just the same way but then for `A10` obviously.

Comment: I'm using 2016 and the answer looks perfect... nearly anyway!  ;-)  Since I have hundreds of rows, is there any way to make the A1 to A10 relative?  I actually will be using B3-B200+ so manual entry would not be so fun... especially with custom input/alert text.

Comment: @Velocedge, select your range `B3-B200` and change `A1` in the formula to `B3`. Not sure what you meant but with *relative* I meant you only need to add this validation formula **once** to the selected range. Another option would be to use an actual table I suppose. Not tested that one.

Comment: My bad... I was selecting the entire column and that didn't work.  When I selected the rows B3:B400 it worked exactly as desired.

Comment: This is crazy... I need to change to allow 0-9 but I can't seem to make that work!

Comment: If you have a different question you can open up one to make it more clear what it is you are after? @velocedge