# Excel: Custom Data Validation for numbers 0-9 or comma separated values 0-9

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I had asked a similar question in:
[Excel: how ensure cells contain numbers 1-6 or comma separated numbers 1-6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63900789/excel-how-ensure-cells-contain-numbers-1-6-or-comma-separated-numbers-1-6)

JvdV gave me a great answer and formula for numbers 1-6 or comma separated.

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[preceding::*=.  or .*0!=0 or .*1>6 or .*1<1]"),"")=""
```

I would have thought it would be easy to modify but obviously, I don't understand the syntax. What is the syntax to allow only the numbers 0-9 or those values separated by commas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[preceding::*=.  or .*0!=0 or .*1>9 or .*1<0]"),"")=""
```

Comment: Yes, that was it.  I'll have to figure out what all that means some day!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) may be a good place to start @Velocedge.